# Sharepoint online - automatic filename based on metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I would like to name the documents in the document library based on meta tags and the document ID sharepoint give the document. Is there any way to achieve this without using sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some sort of workflow or event receiver that will handle that when triggered by an item adding/updated event. Since you're using SharePoint Online, Microsoft Flow may be a simple solution.